# Float to Double adding many 0s at the end of the new double number during conversion

Tags: c++, floating-point, min, numeric-limits

I'm facing a little problem on a personal project:

When I'm converting a float number to a double to make operations (+-*/) easy, it adds a lot of `0`s behind the default float number.

For example: float number = -4.1112 -> double number = -4.1112000000000002

I convert the float to a double with the standard function `std::stod()`.

This issue is a big problem for me cause I'm checking for overflow in my project and it throws an exception because of this issue.

Here is the `checkOverflow` function that throws an exception:

```
{
    if (type == eOperandType::Int8) {
        if (value > std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::max() || value < std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::min())
            throw VMException("Overflow");
    } else if (type == eOperandType::Int16) {
        if (value > std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::max() || value < std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::min())
            throw VMException("Overflow");
    } else if (type == eOperandType::Int32) {
        if (value > std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max() || value < std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::min())
            throw VMException("Overflow");
    } else if (type == eOperandType::Float) {
        if (value > std::numeric_limits<float>::max() || value < std::numeric_limits<float>::min())
            throw VMException("Overflow");
    } else if (type == eOperandType::Double) {
        if (value > std::numeric_limits<double>::max() || value < std::numeric_limits<double>::min())
            throw VMException("Overflow");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. I recommend you write unit test. You can use [Catch2](https://godbolt.org/z/PWrccT).

Comment: What is the type of `value`? Please elaborate on *"I convert the float in a double with the standart function with `std::stod()`"*. What is "float" in that statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is completely different.

All your checks are wrong. Think about it: if a variable is of type, say, `int32_t`, its value is necessarily between the minimum and maximum possible values that can be represented by an `int32_t`, *by definition*. Let's simplify: it's like having a single-digit number, and testing that it is between 0 and 9 (if it is unsigned), or between -9 and +9 (if it is signed): how could such a test fail? **Your checks should never raise an exception.** But, as you say, they do. How is it even possible? And anyway, why would it happen for the long series of zeros that derive from representing -4.1112 as a floating point number, turning it into -4.1112000000000002? That isn't an overflow! This is a strong hint that your problem is elsewhere.

The solution is that `std::numeric_limits<T>::min` doesn't do what you think. As [CPP Reference explains](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min), it gives you the smallest *positive* value:

> For floating-point types with denormalization, min returns the minimum positive normalized value. Note that this behavior may be unexpected, especially when compared to the behavior of min for integral types. To find the value that has no values less than it, use [numeric_limits::lowest](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/lowest).

And the page about `lowest` also provides an example, comparing the output of `min`, `lowest` and `max`:

```
std::numeric_limits<T>::min():  
        float: 1.17549e-38 or 0x1p-126
        double: 2.22507e-308 or 0x1p-1022
std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest():  
        float: -3.40282e+38 or -0x1.fffffep+127
        double: -1.79769e+308 or -0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023
std::numeric_limits<T>::max():  
        float: 3.40282e+38 or 0x1.fffffep+127
        double: 1.79769e+308 or 0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023
```

And as you can see, `min` is positive. So the opposite of `max` is `lowest`.

So you are getting exceptions because your negative values are smaller than the smallest positive value. Or, in other words: because -4 is less than 0.0001. Which is correct. It's the test that is wrong!

You could fix that by using `lowest`... But then, what would your checks tell you? If they ever raised an exception, it would mean that the compiler and/or library that you are using are seriously broken. If that is what you are testing, ok. But honestly I think it will never happen, and you could just delete these tests, as they provide no real value.

Comment: Well done for answering the question (unlike me). Have an upvote.

Comment: To be annoyingly nitpicking, `std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity() > std::numeric_limits<float>::max()`, but that's a corner case.

Answer (score 3):

That's life I'm afraid. A floating point type can only represent a sparse subset of the real numbers.

Assuming IEEE754, the nearest `float` to -4.1112 is `-4.111199855804443359375`

The nearest `double` to -4.1112 is `-4.111200000000000187583282240666449069976806640625`

If you need perfect decimal precision then use a decimal type. There's one in the Boost library distribution. Boost also has a `numeric_cast` function, that does what your function is attempting to do; cleverly, with minimal run-time overhead.